# How to set phone in silent mode or equivalent?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to set my phone in silent mode (no ringtone, no vibrate) without user action.

First of all, `Cortana` does not do what I want as the regional settings is not yet supported and the `Quiet hours` does not support different silent time spans depending on the day of the week and depending on GPS coordinate.

I've search on the internet to find an app with these features but nothing was found.

Write an app came to my mind but settings can't be changed silently. So, I thought to replace the ringtone to a silent one during quiet hours and reset the normal one outside these moments. But, as far as I understand, the ringtone can only be set for the current app.

I'm out of idea, any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Are you looking for a programmatic solution ? If not, I suggest you ask on [Windows Phone Stack Exchange](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a background service, that sets the phone in silent, vibration less mode. The aim is to use

```
HRESULT SetVolume([in]  double Volume);
```

The function is defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj681688(v=vs.105).aspx). So, with this, you can silently change things without user action.